# Will Website Restrictions restrict customer import too?

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, website-restriction

I drilled [this official document](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/event-restrict-access.html) to no avail. I know the frontend customer registration will be restricted. And I tried on admin panal, the restriction take effect too. So if website restriction turn on, customer **import** will also blocked?

Comment: Good Question. Did you try a simple import?

Comment: The import is successful. And I can find my imported customer after reindex.